# Circuit that holds a PIN to GND and leave it floating after power on

Tags: analog, floating, analog-switch, floating-pin

I need a simple circuit that during power on fixes a pin of an IC to GND and after a while leaves this pin floating.
Another circuit should be the same, but fixing another pin to -VEE (-30 V) and then leaving it floating.

A simple MOS or PSMOS used as switch is not enough. An analog switch normally closed from Vishay or Maxim usually can do that to GND but not to -VEE because -30 V as input is out of the maximum rating of these types of devices. So I need two custom circuits but I have no idea.

VCC and VEE are +- 30 V. The pin is an ENABLE of a power amplifier, with 20 kΩ input impedance.

Comment: Perhaps i'm missing something but maybe use a relay instead of a mos/psmos ? e.g. spdt relay, with COM connected to your PIN , the normally closed contact to GND/-Vee and the normally open left floating. Now you simply have to switch the relay whenever you want that pin to float

Comment: Consider a depletion mode FET?

Comment: You might get a specific answer if you mentioned for what purpose you need it. For booting an MCU to proper mode for example.

Answer (score 0):

For both purposes, you can use a single-pole, normally closed bidirectional OptoMOS relay. There is quite a large selection of them. By connecting the control LEDs in series, the two can be switched together.